# How to write file in good format with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, formatting

I'm on a project and trying to write file in python and I'm trying to write a file in nice format. I'd try a lot but I don't know what's going wrong?

**I'd try:**

```
    def generate_file(self, lyrics):
        self.path()
        print('We are writing file ............')
        with open('filename.srt', 'w') as lrc:
            for i in range(len(lyrics)):
                add = ''
                if lyrics[i].isnumeric():
                    add += '\n'
                elif lyrics[i].isalpha():
                    add += '\n\n'
                lrc.write(lyrics[i]+add)
                add += ''
            lrc.close()
            print('We downloaded your file!')
```

**Output:**

000:00:00‚000 --> 00:00:00‚000by RentAnAdviser.com100:00:22‚608 --> 00:00:26‚607Drink from me drink fromme oh ah oh ah200:00:26‚803 --> 00:00:30‚602Then we′ll shoot across the symphony300:00:30‚808 --> 00:00:38‚807Then we′ll shoot across the sky400:00:43‚599 --> 00:00:48‚498Oh angels sent from up above500:00:48‚702 --> 00:00:53‚801You know you make my world light up600:00:54‚005 --> 00:00:59‚004When I was down when I was hurt700:00:59‚218 --> 00:01:04‚717You came to lift me up800:01:04‚911 --> 00:01:09‚610Life is a drink and love′s a ****900:01:09‚812 --> 00:01:15‚011Oh now I think I must be miles up1000:01:15‚217 --> 00:01:20‚316When I was hurt withered dried up1100:01:20‚506 --> 00:01:26‚005You came to rain a flood1200:01:26‚217 --> 00:01:28‚716So drink from me drink from me1300:01:28‚900 -

**I excepted:**

0
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
by RentAnAdviser.com

1 
00:00:17,842 --> 00:00:21,341
Drink from me‚ drink from me

2 
00:00:21,537 --> 00:00:23,336
Then we′ll shoot across the sky

3 
00:00:23,546 --> 00:00:24,545
Drink from me‚ drink from me

**How can I do that?**

**My project:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, requests, platform


class EpicLyricFinderApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = '%20'.join(input('Enter song name and also include singer: ').split(' '))
        self.url = 'https://www.rentanadviser.com/en/subtitles/subtitles4songs.aspx?src='+self.text
        self.user = None


        self.app()
    def app(self):
        req = requests.get(self.url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
        print('Please wait ...................')
        tag = soup.findAll('table')
        link = [('https://www.rentanadviser.com/en/subtitles/'+l.get('href'))+'&type=srt' for l in [a.find('a') for a in tag]]
        blank_name = [''.join((l.get_text()).split(' ')[17:]) for l in [a.find('a') for a in tag]]
        [print('No. {} ==>> {}'.format(name+1,blank_name[name])) for name in range(len(blank_name))]


        # Get input form user to choice lyrics
        print('='*60)
        while True:
            try:
                 self.user = int(input('Which lyrics you wanna download?: '))
            except ValueError:
                continue
            else:
                break


        # Open .srt link
        req1 = requests.get(link[self.user]).content
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(req1, 'html.parser')
        lyrics = [c.get_text() for c in soup1.findAll('span', attrs={'id':'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblSubtitle'})]
        self.generate_file(lyrics)





    @staticmethod
    def path():
        if platform.system()=='Linux':
            linux = '/home/rohit/Desktop/lrc'
            if os.path.exists(linux):
                os.chdir(linux)
            else:
                os.mkdir(linux)
                os.chdir(linux)
        else:
            windows = 'Cd:/Users/ABC/rohit/Desktop/lrc'
            if os.path.exists(windows):
                os.chdir(windows)
            else:
                os.mkdir(windows)
                os.chdir(windows)

    def generate_file(self, lyrics):
        self.path()
        print('We are writing file ............')
        with open('_'.join(self.text.split('%20'))+'.srt', 'w') as lrc:
            for i in range(len(lyrics)):
                add = ''
                if lyrics[i].isnumeric():
                    add += '\n'
                elif lyrics[i].isalpha():
                    add += '\n\n'
                lrc.write(lyrics[i]+add)
                add += ''
            lrc.close()
            print('We downloaded your file!')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = EpicLyricFinderApp()
```

Comment: can you just `print( lyrics[:10] )` and see what it looks like ?

Comment: Seems like you're reading the file on Windows but you missed the "\r\n" as EOL.

Comment: Why not use a library already ready to parse and write srt files? https://pypi.org/project/srt/

Comment: try with only one platform, e.g. linux. When everything will work there, make it work on windows.

Comment: I'm using kubuntu linux os.

Comment: I didn't find any vide about python srt to having understanding?